# Parsing XML nodes Key:Value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to parse this example:

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml = '<SelectedValues>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Brand</Name>
    <Value>Baume &amp; Mercier</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>MPN</Name>
    <Value>902</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Model</Name>
    <Value>Baume &amp; Mercier 902</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
</SelectedValues>'

 select c.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') as 'myKey'
        , c.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as 'myValue' 
from @xml.nodes('/SelectedValues//*[not(*)]') as T(c)
```

My desired output should be:

```
myKey myValue
Brand Baume & Mercier
MPN   902
Model Baume & Mercier 902
```

But instead of that I'm getting this one:

[image: xml]

What am I making wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called shredding, the conversion of XML into a relational format.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<SelectedValues>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Brand</Name>
    <Value>Baume &amp; Mercier</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>MPN</Name>
    <Value>902</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Model</Name>
    <Value>Baume &amp; Mercier 902</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
</SelectedValues>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [myKey]
    , c.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [myValue]
FROM @xml.nodes('/SelectedValues/SelectedValue') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+-------+---------------------+
| myKey |       myValue       |
+-------+---------------------+
| Brand | Baume & Mercier     |
| MPN   | 902                 |
| Model | Baume & Mercier 902 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: You made my day. Thanks like this aswell.